# .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, 64-bit

I am so confused that there is no 64-bit .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 1 download? If there is, could anyone send me a link please? My OS is Windows Server 2003 x64. Thanks.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I think [this link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=98106) (NetFx30SP1_x64.exe) is what you want.

I got the information from [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/1b49eb80-093a-4201-982d-b525a5e90c70/).

Comment: Cool, Jon! Question answered!

Answer (score 1):

Just get the [3.5 SP1 download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en) instead. It includes 2.0 SP2 and 3.0 SP2.

Comment: Hi Sören, for project specific reasons, I cannot install 3.5. I need to install 3.0 + SP1. Any ideas?